# What's the role of 名 in Xという名のならず者?

Tags: expressions

I just stumbled across an expression that basically goes like:

> X という名のならず者

(X being the name of a group of people in the story)

I can see what ならず者 means ("bandit", "scoundrel" according to [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A%E8%80%85)) and have a good guess of the general meaning of the sentence, but I have trouble parsing the use of 名 here.

Is 名のならず者 a variant of ならず者, or is this a specific expression involving 名 itself?

Comment: I'm guessing you already know that 名 means 'name'. Can you explain in more detail what your problem is?

Comment: Ah, yes, I do. I'm having trouble figuring out if grammatically I should read it "[Xという名]の[ならず者]" or "[Xという][名のならず者]" (in other words, is 名のならず者 something that can be used standalone?)

Comment: I don't see that it make much difference which way you parse it "scoundrel whose name is X" versus "Scoundrel's name, which is X". Either way it amounts to the same thing: "scoundrel(s) named X". Perhaps these example sentences help: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e5%90%8d%e3%81%ae

Comment: Thank you, that link was actually what I was looking for, the expression wasn't in the dictionaries I usually use... I knew 名 but didn't know for sure that Xという名のY was a correct expression I could use in other contexts. This site is awesome, by the way, I didn't know it existed, bookmarked for later!

Answer (score 1):

名【な】 is "name", and Xという名の～ means "～ named X". This is a set expression.

> Xという名のならず者
> a rogue named X

名の人 doesn't make sense. 名のある人 (or 名がある人) is another set phrase meaning "famous person".